# How to find and replace string using groovy script

Tags: groovy, replaceall

I need to search some text from file and replace with other string using Groovy script. I am explaining my file below.

> test.yml:

```
devices:
  test-server:
    type: test1
    os: test
    tacacs:
      username: admin
    passwords:
      tacacs: admin
    connections:
      defaults:
        class: unicon.Unicon
      cli:
        protocol: ssh
        ip: 1.1.1.1
        port: 2024
      rest:
        protocol: http
        ip: 1.1.1.1
        port: 8080
        username: admin
        password: admin
  RFS1:
    type: test
    os: test
    tacacs:
      username: admin
    passwords:
      tacacs: admin
    connections:
      defaults:
        class: unicon.Unicon
      cli:
        protocol: ssh
        ip: 1.1.1.1
        port: 2024
      rest:
        protocol: http
        ip: 4.4.4.4
        port: 8080
        username: admin
        password: admin
  RFS2:
    type: test
    os: test
    tacacs:
      username: admin
    passwords:
      tacacs: admin
    connections:
      defaults:
        class: unicon.Unicon
      cli:
        protocol: ssh
        ip: 1.1.1.1
        port: 2024
      rest:
        protocol: http
        ip: 6.6.6.6
        port: 8080
        username: admin
        password: admin
```

Here I need to search the `IP` which is under  `devices:/test-server:/connections:/cli:/ip: 1.1.1.1` with some new charcter like `ip:10.10.10.10` using groovy script. I am using below code.

```
def myFile = new File("test.yml") 
def fileText = myFile.text
fileText = (fileText =~ /ip:1.1.1.1/).replaceFirst("ip:10.10.10.10")
myFile.write(fileText)
```

Here my issue is its replacing the required string in whole file where `ip:1.1.1.1` is present but I need to replace under `devices:/test-server:/connections:/cli:/ip: 1.1.1.1`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why not use a proper `.yaml` parser and bind it to an object/map, manipulate the object, hen serialize it to yaml again? I think that would be the right way to do it.

Comment: @ernest_k, I have to trigger it from groovy script. Can you post your answer please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this is to simply do YAML parsing, manipulating the object, and saving back to the file.

Here's an example using Jackson:

```
@Grab(group='com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', 
      module='jackson-dataformat-yaml', 
      version='2.12.2')

def myFile = new File("test.yml")
def om = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper(
             new com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory());
def value = om.readValue(myFile, Map)
value['devices']['test-server']['connections']['cli']['ip'] = '10.10.10.10'
```

That replaces the value in the in-memory object. You can then just save that back to a file, with something like:

```
om.writeValue(myFile, value)
```